# Put image on the right of SVG image on my HTML page instead of on the bottom

Tags: html, css, image, svg

You can see the problem clearly [here.](http://n1t2.info/medianhomePRICE.html) What I want is for the key to be to the right of the SVG image instead of directly below it.  I've tried putting an `<img>` tag inside the svg, outside the svg, I tried wrapping the svg in a body tag then put the key outside of the body, inside the body, nothing seems to be working here.  Any of you wonderful people have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give them both ID or class attributes and limit their widths with CSS rules, like 75% and 20%, whatever. That should already be sufficient (it was when I tried it).

```
<svg id="mysvg" ....... >
<img id="myimg" ....... >

#mysvg { width: 75%; }
#myimg { width: 20%; }
```